# jQuery not working in my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a simple login page right now, but later it would require large amount of `jQuery`, so please suggest a solution.

```js
$('.message a').click(function(){
   $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}
body {
  background: #76b852; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;      
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/login_page.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/login_page.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
      <button>create</button>
      <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div></body>
</html>
```

I have tried including `jQuery` using cdn as well as by downloading it and giving relative path. None of the ways work. I verified that my path is correct using a simple alert function in the `js` file.

It is working here in stackoverflow, when i run the code, but not on my system.

Thanks

Comment: What's not working??

Comment: Current problem is not stated correctly in the question.

Comment: Wraping your jQuery code inside $(document).ready might help.

Comment: @user6507090 For each input you should have a unique name that can identify what input is that.

Comment: Your click function on `.message a` runs perfectly in your sample btw...

Comment: Is your code on a server or in a local file? If it's in a local file you can't leave out the `https:` prefix when accessing the CDN.

Comment: what is wrong with the code.. as you specified everything works fine .  ?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: The jQuery was not getting executed in my local system. As suggested i included the https: prefix, and wrapped my jQuery code in $(document).ready. It is working fine now. Thanks Everyone for quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add your jQuery code on ready event as follows:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('.message a').click(function(){
   jQuery('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
 });
});
```

Also update your jQuery cdn path to 
    https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: Hi. This is working. I don't understand how.  Can you please explain what difference ready made ?

Comment: .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.

Answer (score 1):

CDN path is wrong, try using

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What's the different with `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js` that hes currently using?

Comment: That's the same path, all you did was add the `https:` prefix.

Comment: This answer is correct if he's loading his page from a local file instead of going through a webserver. We should get an answer to that question.

Comment: i am loading my page from a local file not a webserver right now.

Comment: @Barmar It seems that it's indeed running locally *"It is working here in stackoverflow, when i run the code, but not on my system."*.

Comment: yes @Barmar, it is not working as he might be from local with that path and the same code is working with the code snippet

Comment: @user6507090, the issue was with the cdn path , i think it started working after updating cdn url to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js